# several jquery datepicker widgets, add class to only one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a problem with jquery datepicker.

I have a form with several datepicker inputs and one of those inputs I need to select the whole week, while in the other one, I need to work just the regular way; the thing is that when I add the class (ui-weekpicker) to the widget so the first input the user can select the whole week,the class affects all the inputs in the form, at least the hover event, meaning that the other inputs in the onSelect event show the correct date...
How can I prevent this to happen?
here is my code for the week-select datepicker

```
$('#jump-picker').datepicker('destroy').val('').attr('placeHolder','Select Week');
    $('#jump-picker').datepicker( {
        yearRange: "-3:+3",
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        language :'es',
        options: {
            dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
            showAnim   : 'slideDown',
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#jump-picker').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings )
                 + ' - ' + $.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));
            var year = startDate.getFullYear(),
                month = startDate.getMonth(),
                day = startDate.getDate() - startDate.getDay();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar ('gotoDate', year, month, day);

            selectCurrentWeek();        
        },
        beforeShow: function() {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    }).datepicker('widget').addClass('ui-weekpicker').removeClass ('hide-calendar MonthDatePicker HideTodayButton');
    $('.ui-weekpicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.ui-weekpicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
```

thanks for the help

Comment: JQueryUI uses a single `<div>` for all datepicker inputs on the page. Modifying its behaviour to be radically different from one input to another is rarely a trivial task. Could you make a [mcve] illustrating the exact idea behind the question? As written it's a bit difficult to tell

Answer (score 0):

Rather than chaining the call to .addClass('ui-weekpicker') off your $('#jump-picker') selector, add a second invocation to retrieve just one of the elements:

```
$('#jump-picker.week').addClass('ui-weekpicker')
```

or, if you're unable to add a class to one element and not the other

```
$('#jump-picker').first().addClass('ui-weekpicker')
```

will add the class to the first element matched.

As an aside, it's bad practice to use `id`s when you have more than one element, they're supposed to be unique within the document. You'd be best served to use a class for `jump-picker` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The thing is to add the class to the widget corresponding to the input with id #jump-picker, that is as @bigt comented jquery ui adds a single div for all the instances, that's why the error occurs